# Can Azure AD provisioning credentials be updated programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

As the title suggests, does anyone know whether provisioning credentials can be updated programmatically?  Currently whenever I need to update credentials (which for various reasons is fairly frequently) I need to navigate to "Azure AD -> Enterprise Applications -> *Select my application* -> Provisioning -> Update credentials" and then set the *Secret Token* value in *Admin Credentials*.

I've automated everything else in my process but cannot find a way to update these credentials without navigating via Azure Portal.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you tried ?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to accomplish this with Graph API?